# maintain 100% height with vertical window scroll

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I Have a basic bootstrap grid that I need to vertically fill the window regardless of scrolling. Currently, if the window scrolls all styles end sharply at point of scroll.

I need both divs to be the length of the longest of the two divs, and to scroll with each other.

Here is a fiddle of the problem: https://jsfiddle.net/frxpngcn/2/
Thank you.

```
<div class="row">
<div id="nav" class="col-xs-2 col-sm-2 col-md-2 col-lg-2">
    <ul>
        <li>Link</li>
        <li>Link</li>
        <li>Link</li>
        <li>Link</li>
        <li>Link</li>
        <li>Link</li>
        <li>Link</li>
    </ul>
</div>
<div id="main" class="col-xs-10 col-sm-10 col-md-10 col-lg-10">
    <h1>Header</h1>
    <p>content</p>
    <p>content</p>
    <p>content</p>
    <p>content</p>
    <p>content</p>
    <p>content</p>
    <p>content</p>
    <p>content</p>
    <p>content</p>
    <p>content</p>
    <p>content</p>
    <p>content</p>
    <p>content</p>
    <p>content</p>
    <p>content</p>
    <p>content</p>
    <p>content</p>
    <p>content</p>
    <p>content</p>
    <p>content</p>
    <p>content</p>
    <p>content</p>
    <p>content</p>
    <p>content</p>
</div>
</div>

html, body, .row {
    height: 100%;
}

#nav {
    height: 100%;
    background-color: green;
}

#main {
    height: 100%;
    background-color: yellow;
}
```

Comment: add overflow:auto; to #main

Comment: can you show me a fiddle? I lose my scroll bar when trying this.

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/8a74be3L/ the scroll bar is there, you just need to scroll to the right to see it. In bootstrap .row needs to be inside a .container class

Comment: I see, I also need both divs to scroll with each other instead of the main div scrolling independently.

Comment: updated the fiddle to use javascript to get the height of the page and set that to the nav, no using 100% in this version https://jsfiddle.net/8a74be3L/1/

Comment: Looks good, so there's no pure CSS way to do this?

Comment: Not that i can think of. https://jsfiddle.net/8a74be3L/2/ This version just uses the height of the main div and sets that to the nav div, should work out better incase you add a footer at the bottom.

Comment: Found a way to do it in css if it helps, added all these as an answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**CSS Overflow**
https://jsfiddle.net/8a74be3L/

This options makes the main div scroll not the page

```
#main {
    height: 100%;
    background-color: yellow;
    overflow-y:scroll;
}
```

**CSS Padding**
https://jsfiddle.net/8a74be3L/3/

A way to do it in pure css is to add a stupid amount of padding to the bottom and then hide the overflow in the container class.

```
.main-container {
     overflow: hidden;
 }

#nav {
     float: left;
     background-color: green;
     padding-bottom: 500em;
     margin-bottom: -500em;
 }

 #main {
     float: left;
     background-color: yellow;
     padding-bottom: 500em;
     margin-bottom: -500em;
 }
```

**JS Option**
https://jsfiddle.net/8a74be3L/2/

This option uses js to get the height of the main div and set it as the height of the nav div.

```
function resize() {
    var h = document.getElementById('main').offsetHeight;
    document.getElementById("nav").style.height = h + "px";
}
resize();
window.onresize = function () {
    resize();
};
```

Comment: Thanks for the options

Comment: Hi, I found one more problem I'm having with the javascript solution. Either the nav or the main div could be longer depending on the content of the main div. If I am on a page where neither the nav nor the main content take up the full browser window, the heights are cut off at the end of the longest div. I would like the height to continue down to the bottom of the window in this case. Thank you for the help.

Comment: you could change main to the container for both and use the same js to set the height of main https://jsfiddle.net/8a74be3L/4/

Comment: I'm looking at an example where neither div is as long as the browser window and the div styles are cut off at the end of their content. Do I need to set wrapper to 100% height using css for your fiddle to work?

Comment: you'll want to use height on the html and body and min-height on the wrapper, think this is what your after https://jsfiddle.net/eqvu8mdn/