# Disable Scrolling for a window but still scroll a div inside

Tags: javascript, reactjs

So I have this website the drives my boss nuts when he has to scroll through a list.
basically he gets annoyed when the screen scroll, he want only the list inside to scroll not the whole window.

not it's kind of both depending where you put your finger.

I then tried this

```
<ScrollLock>
<container>
some content
<div style ={{
   height: 300px;
   min-height: 300px;
   max-height: 300px;
   overflow-y: scroll;
}}>
my list
</div>
some content
</container>
</ScrollLock>
```

when I use chrome developer tool and use mobile, it works as expected. only the div scrolls. the problem on mobile now nothing scroll at all on both android and iphone.

is there a simple way to lock windows scroll however still scroll div inside ?

Comment: This isn't a react question, this is basic CSS. If you want a single-page app, you set `html` and `body` to `height:100%` with `overflow: hidden`. Done. There is no reason to use "special components" for this, many react things are just plain HTML, CSS, and standard JS things and you just happen to be using React right now ;)

Comment: Is this helpful? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32074698/maintain-100-height-with-vertical-window-scroll There's an example with height 100% there.  And, a demo that's easy to play with or inspect with developer tools.